How to get the unique combinations of values from a column per group and add new columns in the orginal dataframe
I have a dataframe like below :
data = {'RTG_ID': ['AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC','EE','EE','EE','GG','GG','FF','FF'], 'TYPE': ['CD','FF','EF','CD','EG','CD','EF','FF','CD','EF','HH','CD','EG','CD','TT']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


I like to get a count of the combinations based on type and RTG_ID. the order is not matter. It means the combination A,B is same as B,A.
this is my desired output of dataframe :
output = {'RTG_ID': ['AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC','EE','EE','EE','GG','GG','FF','FF'],TYPE': ['CD','FF','EF','CD','EG','CD','EF','FF','CD','EF','HH','CD','EG','CD','TT'],'COMBINATIONS': ['CD,FF,EF','CD,FF,EF','CD,FF,EF','CD,EG','CD,EG','CD,FF,EF','CD,FF,EF','CD,FF,EF','CD,FF,HH','CD,FF,HH','CD,FF,HH','CD,EG','CD,EG','CD,TT','CD,TT'],'COUNT': [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1]}
df_output = pd.DataFrame(output)


I have read How to count the combinations of unique values per group in pandas? but i like to have the combinations added into my orginal dataframe.

If you want to follow the logic of the originally linked post, you could use map:
s = df.groupby('RTG_ID')['TYPE'].agg(frozenset)

df['COMBINATIONS'] = df['RTG_ID'].map(s)
df['COUNT'] = df['COMBINATIONS'].map(s.value_counts())

Output:
   RTG_ID TYPE  COMBINATIONS  COUNT
0      AA   CD  (CD, EF, FF)      2
1      AA   FF  (CD, EF, FF)      2
2      AA   EF  (CD, EF, FF)      2
3      BB   CD      (CD, EG)      2
4      BB   EG      (CD, EG)      2
5      CC   CD  (CD, EF, FF)      2
6      CC   EF  (CD, EF, FF)      2
7      CC   FF  (CD, EF, FF)      2
8      EE   CD  (HH, CD, EF)      1
9      EE   EF  (HH, CD, EF)      1
10     EE   HH  (HH, CD, EF)      1
11     GG   CD      (CD, EG)      2
12     GG   EG      (CD, EG)      2
13     FF   CD      (CD, TT)      1
14     FF   TT      (CD, TT)      1


Since order does not matter, to ensure the same order, consider sorting before combining:
a = df.sort_values('TYPE').groupby('RTG_ID').agg(','.join).rename(columns={'TYPE':'COMBINATIONS'})
df.merge(a.reset_index().merge(a.value_counts().reset_index()))

   RTG_ID TYPE COMBINATIONS  count
0      AA   CD     CD,EF,FF      2
1      AA   FF     CD,EF,FF      2
2      AA   EF     CD,EF,FF      2
3      BB   CD        CD,EG      2
4      BB   EG        CD,EG      2
5      CC   CD     CD,EF,FF      2
6      CC   EF     CD,EF,FF      2
7      CC   FF     CD,EF,FF      2
8      EE   CD     CD,EF,HH      1
9      EE   EF     CD,EF,HH      1
10     EE   HH     CD,EF,HH      1
11     GG   CD        CD,EG      2
12     GG   EG        CD,EG      2
13     FF   CD        CD,TT      1
14     FF   TT        CD,TT      1

